# Significance of making kiddush specifically before eating

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

What is the significance of making kiddush in general before we eat? Do the reasons differ between shabbat and chagim?

Comment: It's not before every meal, only on Shabbos and Yamim Tovim. And we do it because it's a biblical obligation to do so.

Comment: @ezra is it really a biblical obligation to do it before eating?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the intriguing question. Can you clarify what you want to know - Why do we need to make Kiddush, in general, or why is Kiddush made specifically before the meal?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not that I know of. But why should we delay the kiddush until after we stuff our faces? Isn't that sorta rude? Besides, according to the S''A you're not supposed to eat or drink before reciting kiddush.

Comment: @ezra so you're changing to saying the reason is because you don't want to be rude, not because we're biblically obligated to.

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote (originally) for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two aspects to kiddush, in regards to your question. There is the idea of "kiddush hayom" - sanctifying the day, and then there is "kiddush bemakom seudah" - kiddush in the place of the meal.

The main point of kiddush is a mitzva to sanctify the day of Shabbos or Yom Tov, that is, to declare the day as being the holy day that it is. Then there is a rabbinical ammendment to do the kiddush to perform this declaration in the setting of the shabbos meal. The reasons for this vary, but the general idea is that it is fitting to combine two important parts of the shabbos and Yom Tov (Rashbam in psachim).

Comment: scholars refer to this article https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/22429

Comment: Sources would increase the value of this post.

Comment: So what's the significance of making kiddush **before** we eat?

Comment: @Ploni this is basics from arvei psachim, no chiddushim.

Comment: @ABochur i believe the point is that we should not eat before fulfilling our obligations

Comment: @heshy there are no "basics" here. Everything needs a source. Not saying that you can't do without them, but sources will definitely make a better post anywhere.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1714/9643 (CC @ABochur)